# Invalid model identifier in Django Fixture

Tags: python, django, django-models, pyyaml

My django fixture contains the following data:

```
- model: CkProject.NotificationType
  pk: 1
  fields:
    name: comment
    message: commented on your project
```

When I run `python manage.py syncdb`, it shows an error while loading the fixtures:

```
raise base.DeserializationError("Invalid model identifier:
'%s'" % model_identifier)
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture
'....../source/apps/CkProject/fixtures/initial_data.yaml': 
Invalid model identifier: 'CkProject.NotificationType'
```

I have even tried with a json file instead of YAML and same error is returned.

`UPDATE:`
Here is my models.py which is located in apps/Notification/models.py

```
class NotificationType(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'CkProject_notificationtype'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    message = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Have you looked into FactoryBoy? It's a great substitute for normal fixtures! Also could you paste your models.py, please?

Comment: @limelights FactoryBoy seems good. I would look into it. For now, I have included my models.py file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have probably moved your model from `apps/CKProject/models.py` to `apps/Notification/models.py`, so its app_label has changed and the model is identified by Django as `Notification.NotificationType` now. You should update your fixture accordingly.

Alternatively, you can also add `app_label = 'CKProject'` (see: [app_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label)) to NotificationType's Meta object to make Django identify it as `CKProject.NotificationType` again.

Comment: Ya. I have moved the app and this works perfectly. Thanks for the solution. Earlier the app was running on Django 1.5 and naming it as CKProject.Notification (as defined in db_table) worked perfectly. But its showing error on django 1.6.